# is a direct sum of Hilbert spaces a Hilbert space.?

Tags: hilbert-spaces

I have read in [proofwiki](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Hilbert_Space_Direct_Sum_is_Hilbert_Space) that a direct sum of Hilbert spaces is a Hilbert space. However, Wikipedia Page about [direct sum](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum_of_modules#section_7) says it is not necessarily true, that is, the direct sum of Hilbert spaces is not always a complete space. Which of them is right? In what Conditions the direct sum of Hilbert spaces is a Hilbert space?

Comment: Note that proofwiki uses what they call the "Hilbert space direct sum" which is what Wikipedia describes in the relevant section a few lines later, starting with "Alternatively and equivalently ..."

Comment: But Wikipédia presents a condition that is not present on proofwiki: the sum of all norms for each function on the direct sum must converge.

Comment: No, as usual proofwiki is terribly written, but they impose that condition, too: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Hilbert_Space_Direct_Sum

Answer (score 4):

The answer is not in general, in fact you need to add some conditions, please see this proof [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241418/countable-family-of-hilbert-spaces-is-complete/241661#241661), I think it can be of help.